# Get extra Column with sharepoint Lookup column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I work on SharePoint server 2013, in my case i create 2 list (list A and list B)
list A contain 2 columns : Title, Status(Type: Choice) 
list B contain 2 columns : Title, Porject(Type: Lookup to list A)
i want to get one extra column (Status) with this lookup field, but i noticed that the lookup column can only see columns with type (Single line of text)

is there any solution to get this Choice column as extra column with a lookup field?

Answer (score 1):

In **listA**, you can create a `calculated` column that contains the contents of the 'Status' column,
Then, You can add this calculated column to **listB** as an extra column.

Comment: i tried but the column status(type: Choice) was not appeared in list of available columns !

Comment: @user2508328 - I understand, my suggestion is to create a **calculated column** that contains the Status column content. Calculated column does appear in the list of available columns.